# Laravel 5 validation randomly skipping

Tags: php, validation, laravel

First time I encounter this issue, When validating a form:

**Sometimes it just skips the validation and erases all the fields**

When i enter an incorrect emailaddress and keep pressing submit eventually it will reset all the fields at random.. Without giving the "invalid email" error.

These are my rules.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'voornaam' => 'required',
        'achternaam' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'afhalen' => 'required',
        'telefoon' => 'numeric'
    ];
}
```

Any idea's? Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "keep pressing submit" you mean after the page fully loads you click again? And what do you mean by reset all the fields? Are you automaticly refilling the fields when you get redirected back after failed validation?

Comment: Jup, normally when the page reloads the inputs are there with the errors, but when i keep pressing after 3 times or so the page refreshes, the input and the errors are gone.

Comment: Can you show your code to refill the inputs and display the errors?

Comment: It's happening automatically with the new L5 request feature